# Is this an inversion or other construction?

Tags: grammar

> Perched atop a high mountain on the other side, its windows sparkling
>   in the starry sky, was a vast castle with many turrets and towers. 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is this a subject-complement inversion, or some other construction?

Comment: [Cross related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90804/are-the-subject-and-complement-inverted-in-perched-atop-a-high-mountain-on-the)

Comment: You already got an answer to that question. Why would you re-ask the same question?

Comment: @kiam, the first thing I can think of is that OP is not entirely satisfied by the previous answer. However, should we vote to close questions which have already asked on EL&U? If so, how? GR or Dupe?

Comment: If the OP is not entirely satisfied from the previous answer, there is something the OP could do: Offer a bounty for that question. Asking the question here doesn't change the answer; it is not that to an English learner you say something different than what you would say to a entusiast English user.

Comment: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/636/should-we-close-questions-that-are-exact-duplicates-of-open-elu-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's strip out some structurally irrelevant parts...

> 1: Atop the mountain was a castle
>    *...which could equally be expressed as...*
>    2: A castle was atop the mountain

In both, the "subject" is *a castle*, the ["copula"](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/copulaterm.htm) is *was*, and the "complement" is *atop the mountain*.

So yes, either version could be described as an [inversion](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/inversionterm.htm) of the other. But we normally use that term to identify the "poetic, stylised" sequence, where the other is a clearly-identifiable "standard" sequence.

Arguably because English in general tends to favour the [Subject-Verb-Object](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/Svo-Subject-Verb-Object.htm) sequence, one might say #2 above represents the "standard" word order, and #1 is an "inversion". But I can't see this as a particularly useful way of looking at things, since in such descriptive contexts, #1 is actually *more* likely.